# Summary notes for a webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, intellisense

I'm writing a number of web services and wondered if there was any way to publish a summary or some notes so that anyone consuming them can see what the method is for etc.

I'm sure this is either a "not possible" question, or a "very simple to do" one.

I've added xml comments to my methods, but there doesn't appear to be any notes available when I look at the service in the Object Explorer or Intellisense in my test harness application that has consumed the web service.

Web service and winforms test harness application written in C# with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

wsdl:document is unsupported by the XmlSerialiser, but you may have some luck with this http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/